# Large Video FIle Uploading On Vimeo Through Website Fails, Error Connection resets

Tags: php, laravel, file, file-upload, vimeo

I am working with Laravel and my website is uploaded to shared hosting. I made a basic panel to upload video to vimeo using vimeo sdk.
Everything is working fine except when I try to upload larger files, it fails with

**This site can’t be reached**

**The connection was reset.**
**Try:**

- Checking the connection
- Checking the proxy and the firewall

  **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**

I don't have any option to access **httpd** file as suggested in some answers.
However I changed the settings from cpanel as shown in image[image: Changed settings]

My question is- How I can upload large videos without failing?
2. If videos are uploading to vimeo, why do I need to change my upload_max_filesize or any other thing like that.